# How to use ServerValue in FirebaseDatabase plugin for Flutter

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

How to use the ServerValue on [this page](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_database/lib/src/database_reference.dart) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12437) they say the timestamp is implemented for firebase_database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use ServerValue.timestamp to set time

```
   DatabaseReference.set({
  'time': ServerValue.timestamp,
}).
```

Comment: can this solution fix this as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62502699/dart-flutter-not-converting-local-date-time-to-utc-correctly

Comment: Thanks, but this answer is a bit confusing: `DatabaseReference` is a type name and you cannot call `set` on it.