# Dart/Flutter Not converting local date time to UTC correctly

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a flutter/firebase chat app and storing timestamps of messages in UTC. I am using this line of code to convert local time to UTC. `'time': DateTime.now().toUtc().toString(),` When I tested this with two users one is in Virginia, US, and the other one in Sri Lanka. The timestamp of the user in Sri Lanka is converted correctly to UTC, but for user in Virginia time is correct but the date as of yesterday.

Sri Lanka Time: `2020-06-21 20:50:48`

UTC converted: `2020-06-21 15:20:48.027446Z`

Virginia Time: `2020-06-21 11:24:38`

UTC converted: `2020-06-20 15:24:38.594194Z`

My whole app malfunctioned because of this and order of messages got weird. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Firebase-Realtime database then use this code

```
timeStamp = ServerValue.timestamp;
```

If you using Firestore then use this code

```
timeStamp = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the timestamp by yourself. Firestore offers timestamp. See https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FieldValue/serverTimestamp.html

Comment: I am using realtime database, not a firestore. Is there any way to achieve the same in a realtime database?